# Distance between two points in an array

Tags: java, arrays, distance

I'm trying to find out the distance (or the number of "steps") between two points in an array. From anywhere in that array, to any other point.

For example:
If there is a PacMan map which is a 5x5-Matrix and Pacman stands on the field row=0 and column=0 he needs to take 8 steps to get to to the field r=5, c=5.
But how many steps does he need to get to the field 3x3 if Pacman stands on 4x5??
I'm desperately trying to figure that out.

This is what I've got so far:

```
1   public static void path() {
2       int[][] ratings = new int[5][5];
3       int value = 0;
4       for(int i = 0; i<ratings.length; i++) {
5           value = i;
6           for(int j = 0; j<ratings[i].length; j++) {
7               ratings[i][j] = value;
8               value++;
9               System.out.print("-"+ratings[i][j]);
10          }
11          System.out.println();
12      }
13  }
```

Output:

```
-0-1-2-3-4
-1-2-3-4-5
-2-3-4-5-6
-3-4-5-6-7
-4-5-6-7-8
```

As you see I am trying to give every array position a certain path rating. The start point is the spot with the 0. How do I manage to get this output as an example:

```
-3-2-3-4-5
-2-1-2-3-4
-1-0-1-2-3
-2-1-2-3-4
-3-2-3-4-5
```

I hope you people can help me out with this one. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the current X and Y coordinate as parameters. Subtract these from the values and take the absolute. This gives the behavior you want. It is actually always the same distance-table as your first output, but you give it an offset starting position.

For example:

```
Current position (x1,y1) = 4,4.   
Wanted position  (x2,Y2) = 3,2   
Distance = absolute(x2-x1) + absolute(y2-y1) = abs(3-4) + abs(2-4) = 1 + 2 = 3
```

I modified your code to give a correct offset table:

```
public static void path(int currentX, int currentY) {
  int[][] ratings = new int[5][5];
  int value = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i<ratings.length; i++) {
    value = Math.abs(i-currentX);
    for (int j = 0; j<ratings[i].length; j++) {
      ratings[i][j] = value + Math.abs(j-currentY);
      System.out.print("-"+ratings[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Great! :D

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, perhaps more clear, would be to create a custom distance method as follows:

```
static int dist(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
  return Math.abs(x1 - x2) + Math.abs(y1 - y2);
}
```

then use it your loop:

```
public static void path(int currX, int currY) {

  int[][] ratings = new int[5][5];
  for (int i = 0; i < ratings.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ratings[i].length; j++) {
      ratings[j][i] = dist(j, i, currX, currY);
      System.out.print("-"+ratings[j][i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```